# Firebase DB- How to read particular value of child in Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how my Databse looks:[image: see in the image for the database structure]

I want to read the value of field state using Node js

Comment: This is very simple and you can find that at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data. So before posting question search on google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using client-SDK then you can do following. Same applies to admin SDK but few initializations will differ.

I am taking rooms node as parent node

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database';

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const dbRootRef = firebaseApp.database().ref();

dbRootRef.child(`Rooms/${your_rooom_id}/roomdetails/01/1/appliance/0/state`)
    .once('value')
    .then((snapshot) => {
        const snapshotValue = snapshot.val();
            return snapshotValue; // note that db will return null if no value found or node does not exist
    });
```

This is very simple and you can find that in [official firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data). So before posting basic questions you should search on google

Comment: Thanks dude ,not from JS or Node JS background ;)